# Webform - broken link when trying to pass values

Tags: drupal-webform

I've got a custom module that takes the email address from a form and inserts a link in the email handler (via a token) that when clicked on goes to another webform and when submitted sends the reply to the original email address.

What I'm trying to do is pass the submitted values from the first form in to this link but it's not working:

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter() for webform.
 *
 * Add the custom validation handler to the 'webform-1'.
 */
function webformcustom_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'webform_submission_get_offers_add_form') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'webformcustom_validator';
  }
}

/**
 * The custom validation handler.
 *
 * Get an email of a user, encrypt it and insert it
 * into the body of the notification email.
 * Generate a random token and store it with a user's email as a 'key'/'value'
 * using State API.
 * A token that is added to the link on the webform_2 as the argument,
 * like this: http://drupal8.dev/form/webform-2?token=fb41566252aec769.
 * This token then will be using in the hook_preprocess_HOOK() for extraction
 * of a user's email.
 */
function webformcustom_validator(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $email = $form_state->getValue('email_address');


  $webform = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('webform')
    ->load('get_offers');

  $email_handler = $webform->getHandler('email');
  $configuration = $email_handler->getConfiguration();
  // Generate a random token.
  $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8));
  \Drupal::state()->set('webformcustom_' . $token, $email);

  $url = \Drupal::urlGenerator()->generateFromRoute('<front>', [], ['absolute' => TRUE]);
  $url .= 'provide-a-quote/?select_a_car=[webform-submission:values:select_a_car]&token=' . $token;

  // Insert the link to the 'webform-2' with the token into the email body.
  $configuration['settings']['body'] = '<a href=' . $url . '>Submit offer</a>';
  $email_handler->setConfiguration($configuration);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for webform templates.
 *
 * Read the token from the url and extract related a user's email.
 * Then set a user's email in to the email handler configuration.
 * This enables to notify a user when the 'webform_2' will be submit.
 */
function webformcustom_preprocess_webform(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#webform_id'] == 'provide_a_quote') {

    $token = \Drupal::request()->query->get('token');
    $email = \Drupal::state()->get('webformcustom_' . $token);

    $webform = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('webform')
      ->load('provide_a_quote');

    $email_handler = $webform->getHandler('email');
    $configuration = $email_handler->getConfiguration();

    $configuration['settings']['to_mail'] = $email;
    $email_handler->setConfiguration($configuration);
    $webform->save();
  }
}
```

What it gives me as a link on the email is a broken link:

Audi?token=01f89ea29aa5251f>The link to the webfrom-2

Comment: You should provide code of your custom module, and the html source where the broken link should be, to check the presence of the tag "a href=". For know I suspect an invalid character in the url.

Comment: I've provided the entirety of my custom module code, see above. The HTML source is an email that gets generated automatically.

Comment: What must be in [webform-submission:values:select_a_car], before the 'Audi'? Also try urlencode / urldecode this input.

Comment: Webform 1 has email address and select a car.

This custom module lets webform 2 read the email address via the token.

Webform 2 when submitted replies to the email address. [webform-submission:values:select_a_car] is what is returning "Audi" in the broken link. When I go back to my original code the link looks and works with the text "Submit offer" - with the code it just breaks it and throws out plain text as "Audi?token=01f89ea29aa5251f>Submit Offer"